# Dynamodb partition key strategy - multiple owners

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema

I am finding it difficult to understand the best attribute(s) to use as a partition key for my application as I am new to DynamoDB. I am trying to use DynamoDB for a simple application where pairs of users are randomly selected to meet up and get introduced with one another. I need to choose appropriate tables and partitioning strategies that would help with the following query:

> Retrieve the meetup (introduction) the user has been invited to. It should show all
>   the details of the meetup including the other invited user.

From what I have understood from the docs, to "query" an item, I can only use the keys in the query expression. In addition, a good partition key is one that that has high cardinality and promotes equal distribution in read/write throughput activity. I was thinking of creating a `Meetup` table but im struggling with choosing a partition key especially when the meetup is "owned" by 2 users and the event item will expire(be non-active) after the meetup occurs so I'm not sure that using the `meetupID` is a good idea. But I was thinking of using two tables as such:

**Invitation Table:**

- userId (partition key)
- eventId (sort Key)
- some attribute
- another attribute

**MeetUp Table:**

- meetupId (partition key) -> I'm hesitant about this
- invitedUsers (this is going to be an array of user objects)
- cancelled
- meetDate

With this solution, 2 requests would need to be done to firstly get the latest eventId and then to get the event details. Does this seem like a good approach? Is the meetupId a good partition key? is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of meetups per users follows a normal distribution, you should be able to safely have something like this:

- A *users* table :: Partition key = user_id (some UUID)
- A *meetups* table :: Partition key = meetup_id (some UUID)
- A *meetup_invites* table: Partition key = user_id, Sort key = meetup_id

At large scale, the above could only become problematic, if, say, you had some users with a million invites when the average invite per user would be very small.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. So to obtain the results needed, I'd have to do 2 round trips to the DB and execute two queries... Right?

Comment: Yep - That's a very common pattern with DynamoDB.

Comment: If you don't expect to have many invites per user, you could also have an invites field in the users table that holds an array of the associated meetup IDs.

Comment: Thanks again Daniel, I do not expect to have many invites to a specific user. All users are going to get a random invite every month for them to meet. I am planning to potentially start two tables: A `users` table with a `meetups` array attribute as well as a `meetups` table with a `users` array attribute. I not very confident about this, but it seems that I may not need that `invites` pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this schema.

```
| ID (PK)   | SortKey          | MeetupId (GSI1) | 
| User1234  | metadata         |                 | age:28 | nationality: US | interestedIn:Economics | name:Tim  | ...
| User1234  | meetup#meet1234  |      meet1234   | ...
| meet1234  | metadata         |      meet1234   | location:Central Park | time:122323223 | ...
| User4567  | metadata         |                 | age:27 | nationality: US | interestedIn:Arts | name:Kira  | ...
| User4567  | meetup#meet1234  |      meet1234   | ...
...
Id is sortkey for GSI1
```

this will solve use cases like

1. Get all meetups User1234 is invited to
   `Select * where id=User1234 and SortKey startswith meetup`
2. Get all meetups User1234 is invited to in 10 days
   `Select * where id=User1234 and SortKey startswith meetup filter eventDate < today +10`
3. Get userInfo for user1234 `Select where id=User1234 and SortKey=metadata`
4. Get all invitees for meet1234 `Select * where MeetupId=meet1234 and SortKeystarts with User From Table GSI1`
5. Get all details about event meet1234 `Select * where MeetupId=meet1234  From Table GSI1`

Unsolved use cases:

1. Get all meetups happening today.

In NoSql schema should be driven from use cases.